# if statement is not working and I'm getting a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: java, android

I have this app that takes data from a user and inserts it into an SQLite database. that information is then put into an array and displayed to the user via a `textView` that can be scrolled.

The app runs into a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` error when you try to use it if you haven't inserted anything in the database to be displayed I got around this with a simple if statement.

Here's the code so you can see what im talking about-

```
public void mode(){
    if (array.isEmpty() == false && end == 0) {
        textView.setText(array.get(currentPos));

        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                currentPos++;
                if (currentPos > array.size() - 1) currentPos = 0;
                textView.setText(array.get(currentPos));


            }
        });

        prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                currentPos--;
                if (currentPos < 0) currentPos = array.size() - 1;
                textView.setText(array.get(currentPos));
            }
        });


    } else {
        textView.setText("Nothing to display yet.");

    }
}
```

This was a work around to the problem so I could still scroll the array without causing an error if there's nothing in it.

However when I added functionality to delete an item from the database
Here's the code for that-

```
public void DeleteData(){

        removeBtnInsideMenu.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean deletedRows = myDB.deleteData(textView.getText().toString());
                        if (deletedRows == true){
                            Toast.makeText(thisMenu.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            array.clear(); //clears array
                            viewAll(); //recalls database and refills array
                            if (array.isEmpty() == false){ //plays if the array has something in it
                                onLeftSwipe();
                            }
                            if (array.isEmpty()){
                                 checker = true;
                                 end++;
                            }

                        }
                        else if (array.isEmpty() && checker == true){
                            favoriteCurrent.setText("Nothing to display yet.");
                            Toast.makeText(thisMenu.this, "Everything has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            end++;
                            checker = false;


                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(thisMenu.this, "There is nothing to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            end++;


                        }


                    }
             }
     );
 }
```

I ran into the issue again after everything has been deleted from the database (and subsequently the array) the error pops up again in a very specific place basically when you press the buttons next/prev you get an out of bounds error. I'm completely confused by this because the if statement should just handle it by not allowing that section of code to run, I even added an extra parameter with an int called end that was set to 0 and then incremented up at the end of the app so the if statement wouldn't be true if you deleted everything it should just default to the else statement.

Im confused on this one unless im missing something minor or there's some issue I'm not aware of- any help would be appreciated.

just for clarity heres the logcat error if that helps-

```
12-17 11:48:27.584 29014-29014/com.ded.www.rj E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                               Process: com.ded.www.rj, PID: 29014
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.ded.www.rj.thisMenu$1.onClick(thisMenu.java:166)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please make the question as short as possible, post the code where exactly you are having the problem. Dont post all your codes and dont write big paragraph .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your onClickListeners are getting set once you have some data in the database. So after you add some data, then subsequently call your delete method, the previous and next buttons are still trying to step through the array when clicked. Since the data has been deleted, it's causing your out of bounds error.

I would add an if statement inside the onClick methods, so it doesn't try to step through the array if it's empty.